# .NET Core Entity Framework Fluent api error, DateTime properties have text as column type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

In my model namespace, I have different model classes. I have `DateTime` fields in my different classes. When I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

without problem, it adds a migration and I am able to update the database too.

When I looked up my `initialCommit.Designer.cs`, I saw that all of my `DateTime` properties have column type text.

Like this:

```
namespace myapp.API.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string KnownAs { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }
        ..
    }
}

namespace myapp.API.Models
{
    public class Photo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public bool IsMain { get; set; }
        public string PublicId  { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace myapp.API.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
    [Migration("20200206201625_initialCommit")]
    partial class initialCommit
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.1.1");

            modelBuilder.Entity("myapp.API.Models.Photo", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("DateAdded")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<bool>("IsMain")
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<string>("PublicId")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Url")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<int>("UserId")
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("UserId");

                    b.ToTable("Photos");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("myapp.API.Models.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("BirthDate")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("City")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Country")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("CreatedOn")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Gender")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Interests")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Introduction")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("KnownAs")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("LastActive")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("LookingFor")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<byte[]>("PasswordHash")
                        .HasColumnType("BLOB");

                    b.Property<byte[]>("PasswordSalt")
                        .HasColumnType("BLOB");

                    b.Property<string>("UserName")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Users");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("myapp.API.Models.Value", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Type")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Values");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("myapp.API.Models.Photo", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("myapp.API.Models.User", "User")
                        .WithMany("Photos")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all of my `DateTime` fields are defined like this :

```
b.Property<DateTime>("DateAdded").HasColumnType("TEXT");
```

Comment: What database are you targeting? SQLite is the only one that could behave like this because it [doesn't really have date types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Dates are stored as ISO8601 date literals. If you use SQLite, which provider did you use?

Comment: Hi i used SQLite for development, in production i have switched to MySql and after the this error occured i dropped database added migration again but i did not delete my migrations folder. Do i need to delete my migration folder and drop database ?

Comment: If you target a new database you don't need migrations. You're starting from scratch. You can't use the same migrations for different products either, not when they specify product-specific types. Different databases have different types. *NO* database is fully ANSI-SQL compliant - it's impossible to do so. The standard is huge and committee-driven. All vendors have extra types and features

Comment: So what do you purpose? For the Mysql database i need to remove all my migrations and add a new migration again? By the way by you mean which provider is this?,services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(prm => prm.UseSqlite
            (Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });

Answer (score 0):

you can set the columtype yourself;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>.Property<b=>BirthDate>().HasColumnType("date");
```

Comment: I dont want to manually change my migration every time i add a migration. Making this like paper over cracks, i want to find the main reason of the problem.

Comment: @FurkanKaracan The problem is the wrong type, and trying to use migrations created for one database product work with a completely different one. You need *different* migrations for different products. *No* database is fully ANSI-SQL compliant - it's impossible.